# Will using UUID to as list keys cause unnecessary re-renders in React?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I have a list of items that doesn't contain enough data to generate a unique key. If I use the uuid library to generate an ID, will a single item change also causes the other items to re-render since their key will change each time?

```
const people = [
  {
    gender: 'male',
    firstName: 'david',
  },
  {
    gender: 'male',
    firstName: 'david',
  },
  {
    gender: 'male',
    firstName: 'joe',
  },
]

const renderPeople = () => {
  return people.map(person => {
    return (
      <div key={uuid.v4() /* a new value each time? */ }>
        <p>{person.gender}</p>
        <p>{person.firstName}</p>
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

some time later... one of the davids changed

```
const people = [
  {
    gender: 'male',
    firstName: 'david',
  },
  {
    gender: 'male',
    firstName: 'davidzz',
  },
  {
    gender: 'male',
    firstName: 'joe',
  },
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When giving unique keys to components, is it okay to use Math.random() for generating those keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808636/when-giving-unique-keys-to-components-is-it-okay-to-use-math-random-for-gener)

Comment: @devserkan I don't think that thread fully solves my problem as generating a UUID at fetch time will still creates new UUIDs for the same data.

Comment: You are right but as you can see there aren't much more options. We can't talk about different options here I think, all the suggestions will be so similar (This is why I voted this question as a duplicate). Either you will create a unique id with some properties (you don't have much here) or you will use the index if the order won't change or you will give to the objects some unique id in the creation time (if you are the one creating them). Other than that, if there will be any different options I also want to hear.

Comment: @devserkan Thanks for the detail explanation and the other link. Yes there is always a possibility that there is no good solution, just want to check with the SO community before I commit :)

Answer (score 31):

`<div key={uuid.v4()}>` assigns new key for each `<div>` every time, so it is useless.

If the array stays same, UUID should be generated on array creation.

If the array changes, e.g. received from HTTP request, UUIDs for elements with same content will be generated again.

In order to avoid that, `key` should be specific to `person` entity. It's always preferable to use internal identifiers (database IDs) where available for unambiguity.

If identifiers are not available, `key` may depend on element contents:

```
return (
  <div key={JSON.stringify(person)}>
    <p>{person.gender}</p>
    <p>{person.firstName}</p>
  </div>
)
```

It's more efficient to hash elements once at the time when an array is created, e.g. with `uuid`:

```
import uuidv3 from 'uuid/v3';
...

for (const person of people) {
  person.key = uuidv3(JSON.stringify(person), uuidv3.URL);
}
```

Or use dedicated hashing function like [`object-hash`](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash).

Notice that hashing may result in key collisions if there are elements with same contents.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Keys should be stable. If they're not, React can't infer that these items might be the same at all, and has to fully rerender them.