# React: How to display a modal without encountering error message (details provided)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

**Intro**

When my application starts, a list of images appear. If additional details about an image is required, a user can click on an image that has previously loaded, and a modal would appear with it's relevant details.

Even though everything works as it should, I'm encountering an error message that can be found in Chrome browser's console.

**Error**

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

**Attempted**

I've tried placing `key={Math.floor(Date.now() * 20)}` within the `Image` found in the modal, but that doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong? How can I fix this issue?

```
  function getHomePage() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false);
  const [NFTBalances, setNFTBalances] = useState();
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState();
  const [nft, setNft] = useState();
  const { Moralis } = useMoralis();

  //load my images when application starts
  useEffect(() =>  {
    collectionChanged('myCollection');
  }, []);
    
const handleSelectToken = async (num, col) => {
    if (num && col) {
      const dbNFTs = Moralis.Object.extend(col);
      const query = new Moralis.Query(dbNFTs);
      console.log(num);
      query.equalTo("tokenId", num);
      let selectedNFT = await query.first();
      selectedNFT = selectedNFT.attributes;
      console.log(selectedNFT);
      setNft(selectedNFT);
      setVisibility(true);

      //open modal
      $("#openModal").modal("show");
    }
  };


  const addToNFTs = async (col) => {
    const dbNFTs = Moralis.Object.extend(col);
    const query = new Moralis.Query(dbNFTs);
    query.ascending("rank");
    query.limit(4);
    const topNFTs = query.skip(NFTBalances.length);
    const results = await topNFTs.find();
    setNFTBalances(NFTBalances.concat(results));
  }

return (
  <>
//modal box
      <div className="modal fade" id="openModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
           <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
              <div className="modal-content">
                 <div className="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" className="close" 
                         data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                 </div>
                 <div className="modal-body">
                   <div>
                     <Image key={Math.floor(Date.now() * 20)} 
                         preview={false} src={nft.image} loading="lazy"
                         style={{ display: "block", width: "50%"}}/>    

                       <p>{nft.details}</p> 
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
     </div>

 
               <div className="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                    <div className="filter-sidebar">
                       <div className="filter-sidebar-content">
                          <div className="form-group">

                             //SEARCH BOX
                             <Search placeholder="Please search here"
                                   onChange={(e) => setToken(e.target.value) }
                                   onSearch={() => handleSelectToken(token, collection)} />
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>

   

//Images populate when application loads
//Clicking an image will populate image details in a modal
    <div className="row">
          {NFTBalances && NFTBalances.map((nft, index) => {
             return (
               <div className="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                 <div className="card items">
                   <Card key={index} onClick={() => 
                      handleSelectToken(nft.attributes.tokenId,collection)}
                          cover={ <Image src={nft.attributes.image} /> }>
                   </Card>
                  </div>     
                </div> 
                 );})}
   </div>          
   </>        
      );}

export default getHomePage;
```

Comment: On what exact line the warning 'Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.' is pointing on? can you post the full console log ?

Answer (score 1):

In `modal box` the `key` for the `<Image>` is causing an issue since **the key values need to be unique**.

By setting `key={Math.floor(Date.now() * 20)}`, every `<Image>` will end up with the same `key` since they are rendered at the same time.

You should be able to just remove `key` from that line:

```
<Image preview={false} src={nft.image} loading="lazy" style={{ display: "block", width: "50%"}}/>
```

But if that ends up giving you issues, you could also generate a key randomly:

```
<Image key={Math.random().toString()} preview={false} src={nft.image} loading="lazy" style={{ display: "block", width: "50%"}}/>
```

I don't know what your `nft` object looks like, but if each one has its own unique `id`, that `id` would be ideal to use for `key`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813867/15351640) explains why that is.

```
<Image key={nft.id} preview={false} src={nft.image} loading="lazy" style={{ display: "block", width: "50%"}}/>
```

---

Another issue is that **there is no key being set** on the immediate child inside of `.map`. You should be setting the `key` on the `div` that comes right after `return`:

```
{NFTBalances && NFTBalances.map((nft, index) => {
             return (
               <div key={index} className="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                 <div className="card items">
                   <Card onClick={() => 
                      handleSelectToken(nft.attributes.tokenId,collection)}
                          cover={ <Image src={nft.attributes.image} /> }>
                   </Card>
                  </div>     
                </div>
```

Good luck! They `key` prop is pretty important in React. Here's a bit [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/15351640) from a great answer about `key` if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

```
{NFTBalances && NFTBalances.map((nft, index) => {
  return (
    <div className="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
```

Keys are needed when you make an array of elements, and so this `<div>` is where you need to put the key. Ideally, it will be some unique identifier found in the `nft` object. Since i don't know the structure of your data i can't be sure the best value to use, but assuming `nft.attributes.tokenId` is unique and always present:

```
<div key={nft.attributes.tokenId} className="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
```

If there is no unique identifier on `nft`, then as a last resort you could use the `index`, but this will only work correctly if you are not rearranging this list.

```
<div key={index} className="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
```

> key={Math.floor(Date.now() * 20)}

This is a bad key. First, it's not going to be unique: all these `<div>`s are being created at basically the same time, so in all likelyhood they'll all get the same value for Date.now(). Second, they are going to change from one render to the next.

The point of keys in react is to tell react which element in the first render corresponds to which element in the second render. If they're all changing, then react thinks it needs to throw out everything and start again (ie, it must unmount and remount all the components)

Answer (score 1):

You're placing the key at the wrong place. You're not rendering a list of images, but rather a list of cards containing images, here is where you need to add the key prop. You've already added a key to the card itself, butit needs to be present on the parent element. You can use index only if you do not expect the order of these to change during render. Alternatively use your `key={Math.floor(Date.now() * 20)}`.

```
        {NFTBalances && NFTBalances.map((nft, index) => {
         return (
           <div key={index} className="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
             <div className="card items">
               <Card onClick={() => 
                  handleSelectToken(nft.attributes.tokenId,collection)}
                      cover={ <Image src={nft.attributes.image} /> }>
               </Card>
              </div>     
            </div> 
             );})}
           </div>          
          </>        
         );}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, that didn't fix my problem. Is there a way to suppress the error message instead?

Comment: You could ignore it, it shouldn't have any effect on the rendering. But it would be optimal to fix this. What line is the error pointing to?