# React.js "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having issues adding a key to my list. When I use index I get the error: "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.".

```
const selectPfp = pfps?.map((e: string, i:number) => {
return (
  <>
    <PfpOption
    key={i}
      active={selectedPFP && selectedPFP === e}
      src={e}
      onClick={() => {
        setSelectedPFP(pfps[i]);
        console.log("clicked");
      }}
    />
  </>
);
```

})

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @SakibulAnwar Bad idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808636/when-giving-unique-keys-to-components-is-it-okay-to-use-math-random-for-gener

Comment: @SakibulAnwar thank you for the reply. Sadly this didn't work either, I feel like it's ignoring the key entirely for some reason.

Comment: Beware using the index as a key, see @GiorgiMoniava's link for why, and thr blog post that page links to.

Answer (score 5):

The key must be put into the *outermost* component's prop when returning from a `.map`. Here, the outermost component is the plain fragment, so do

```
return (
  <React.Fragment key={i}>
    <PfpOption
      active={selectedPFP && selectedPFP === e}
      ...
```

That said, because there's only one child of the fragment, it's completely superfluous; you may remove it entirely and do

```
const selectPfp = pfps?.map((e: string, i: number) => {
    return (
        <PfpOption
            key={i}
            active={selectedPFP && selectedPFP === e}
            src={e}
            onClick={() => {
                setSelectedPFP(pfps[i]);
                console.log("clicked");
            }}
        />
    );
})
```

Because `e` is the item in the array being iterated over, you can also replace `pfps[i]` with `e`. (you could also consider using a more precise variable name to make it more clear - maybe `pfp`?)