# Choose react key for a list with duplicate items

Tags: reactjs

I need to render a list with string items like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']`, the items are allowed to be duplicate to each other, what is the proper way to choose a react key in `{list.map(x => <span key={?}>{x}</span>)}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When giving unique keys to components, is it okay to use Math.random() for generating those keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808636/when-giving-unique-keys-to-components-is-it-okay-to-use-math-random-for-gener)

Answer (score 6):

This should work

```
{list.map((x,i) => <span key={`${x}-${i}`}>{x}</span>)}
```

Comment: Using indexes as key is a bad practice, ES Lint should complain if you have it enabled in your IDE. React documentation also states why  it's a bad practice: https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys